# AMD instance module that uses its own constructor - Durandal

Tags: javascript, c#, requirejs, amd, durandal-2.0

In a Durandal app with MVC + Web API back-end I have the following `C#` class:

```
public class ProductFilter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ProductFilter> DependentFilters { get; set; }
}
```

I have a front-end instance model `filter.js` that I want to map to this class. It currently looks like this:

```
define(["models/filter"], function (filter) {
    return function (data) {
        var self = this;
        data = data || {};

        self.name = ko.observable(ko.unwrap(data.name || ""));

        self.dependentFilters = ko.observableArray();

        $.each(ko.unwrap(data.dependentFilters || []), function () {

            // ---> 'filter' is undefined, so I cannot call new filter(..)
            self.dependentFilters.push(new filter(this));
        }); 
    };
});
```

As you can see, the `C#` class has a collection of its own type, and I need to replicate that structure on the Durandal model. In the example above I've tried injecting the `filter.js` module into itself, but `RequireJs` doesn't seem to like that as the `filter` variable is always `undefined`.

My problem probably stems from a lack of `RequireJs` or `AMD` modules knowledge, but how can I actually call the constructor of the current module within itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the function so that it has an name, and just call it from itself. You can then return the function by referring to it by name:

```
define(function () {
    function filter (data) {
        // ... same as in your question ...
        $.each(ko.unwrap(data.dependentFilters || []), function () {
            self.dependentFilters.push(new filter(this));
        }); 
    };

    return filter;
});
```

Comment: Brilliantly simple. Thanks!